# Building and Grouping JSON Object in SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have the following table and I'm trying to combine the rows into JSON objects.

| Username | AccessKeys | Marker |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | `{"Account":"1","Checking":"0001","Loan":"null","Savings":0}` | New |
| user2 | `{"Account":"2","Checking":"0001","Loan":"null","Savings":0}` | New |
| user2 | `{"Account":"3","Checking":"0001","Loan":"null","Savings":0}` | New |

The result should look something like this.

| Username | JSON |
| --- | --- |
| user1 | `{"Accounts": [{"Account": "1","Checking": "0001","Loan": null,"Savings": 0}],"Marker": "New"}` |
| user2 | `{"Accounts": [{"Account": "1","Checking": "0001","Loan": null,"Savings": 0},{"Account": "2","Checking": "0001","Loan": null,"Savings": 0}],"Marker": "New"}` |

My current query is this.  I've been able to get this far but not sure how to proceed from here.

```
SELECT
     Username
    ,Accounts = (
        SELECT
             Account
            ,Checking
            ,Loan
            ,Savings
        FROM dbo.Accounts A1
        WHERE A1.Account= A2.Account
        FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER 
     )
FROM
    dbo.Accounts A2
GROUP BY
     Accounts
    ,Username
;
```

Thanks in advance!

## Solution

This is my final query.

```
SELECT
  Username
 ,(
      SELECT
           Accounts = JSON_QUERY((
           SELECT AK.*
           FROM
                dbo.Accounts A2
                CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(Accounts) WITH (
                      Account nvarchar(10)
                     ,Checking nvarchar(10)
                     ,Loan nvarchar(10)
                     ,Savings int
                ) AK
           WHERE A2.Username = A1.Username
           FOR JSON PATH
           ))
           ,'New' Marker
      FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
 ) JSON
FROM dbo.Accounts A1
GROUP BY Username
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SQL Server creating JSON array elements usually involves [json_query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql), such as...

```sql
select
  Username,
  [JSON] = (
    select
      [Accounts] = json_query((
        select AK.*
        from dbo.Accounts A2
        cross apply openjson(AccessKeys) with (
          Account nvarchar(10),
          Checking nvarchar(10),
          Loan nvarchar(10),
          Savings int
        ) AK
        where A2.Username = A1.Username
        for json path
      )),
      [Marker]
    for json path, without_array_wrapper
  )
from dbo.Accounts A1
group by Username, Marker;
```

Which yields the results...

| Username | JSON |
| --- | --- |
| user1 | {"Accounts":[{"Account":"1","Checking":"0001","Loan":"null","Savings":0}],"Marker":"New"} |
| user2 | {"Accounts":[{"Account":"2","Checking":"0001","Loan":"null","Savings":0},{"Account":"3","Checking":"0001","Loan":"null","Savings":0}],"Marker":"New"} |

Comment: I ended up using a version of your query.  I was beating my head against a wall for hours.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

**You can use `ROOT` to add a root property,** and remove `WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER` becaus eyou actually want the array here.

```sql
SELECT
     Username
    ,JSON = (
        SELECT
             Account
            ,Checking
            ,Loan
            ,Savings
        FROM dbo.Accounts A1
        WHERE A1.Username = A2.Username
        FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('Accounts')
     )
FROM
    dbo.Accounts A2
GROUP BY
     A2.Username;
```

This does have the downside of re-querying the table. To improve performance, you could construct the JSON manually using `STRING_AGG` (SQL Server does not have `JSON_AGG` unfortunately).

```sql
SELECT
     Username
    ,JSON = (
       SELECT Accounts = JSON_QUERY('[' + STRING_AGG(
         (SELECT
             A.Account
            ,A.Checking
            ,A.Loan
            ,A.Savings
         FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
        ), ',') + ']')
       FOR JSON PATH)
FROM
    dbo.Accounts A
GROUP BY
     A.Username;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, this is SQL Server 2016 which doesn't have the STRING_AGG function.